# How to find a peak in an array?

Tags: algorithm

Given an array such as

```
[69,20,59,35,10]
```

I would like to discover all peaks in this array. By the definition of the problem, a peak is an element pi of the array that satisfy the property p_k < p_i > p_j with k < i < j. I'm not interested just in the neighbors of an certain element, I want to analyze all elements before and after this element. With this definition and this example we have the following peaks:

```
[20,59,35]

[20,59,10]

[20,35,10]
```

What kind of algorithm or approach I have to use to deal with this?

Comment: In the worst case array might contain O(n^2) peak triplets (for example: 01010101010101), so any quadratic algo seems good enough.

Comment: @MBo I think the worst case is actually O(n^3)? For input like `000011110000`.

Comment: @eldar Yes, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the total number of peaks in the worst case would be on the order of `O(n^3)`, therefore an optimal algorithm that outputs all peaks cannot be better than `O(n^3)` - and the other answers provide cubic-time implementations. An example of an input that has this order of peaks is `00...011...100..0`, where each of the three segments of identical characters is of equal length.

However, assuming that you are interested in counting the number of peaks rather than outputting each of them, there is a much faster `O(n logn)` solution. You can implement a BST (Binary Search Tree) that supports computing ranks (i.e., each node knows how many nodes are to its left - that is, how many values are below it) in logarithmic time. Create two BSTs - one will store the element to the left of the current wannabe peak, and the other to its right. For each i from 1 to n-1, assume it is the middle and find how many pairs of indices would work with it. Every value in the first BST that's lower than the i-th element could be the left index, and every value in the second BST that's lower than the i-th element could be the right index. Hence, the product of these counts is how many peaks with i-th element in the middle exist.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your arrays are 0-indexed, you can use the algorithm below:

```
i = 1
while i < length(array) - 1 do
    c = array[i]
    j = 0
    while j < i do
        k = i + 1
        while k < length(array) do
            l = array[j]
            r = array[k]
            if c > l and c > r then
                write('found peak: ', [l, c, r])
            k = k + 1
        j = j + 1
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: I forgot to tell but the problem has a limit to run and the input size is 10^5 so this algorithm doesn't run with this limits. This was the first ideia that I had.

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing this figure I drew, in case this can help you to clearly understand what is going on and build a more optimal algorithm.

This is the pseudo code:

1. **Cp** is a **positive counter**: increase it when going uphill
2. **Cn** is a **negative counter**: increase it when going downhill
3. Reset **Cp** and **Cn** when **moving horizontally,** or when we have **reach** a **valley** (Opposite of a Peak).
4. If **array[i] > array[i-1]** and **array[i] > array[i+1]**, then **array[i]** is a **peak**. The opposite of this statement can be used to find when we reach a **valley**
5. After we reach the peak, keep incrementing Cn (Cn += 1) until an eventual reset of Cn.
6. Right before resetting Cn to zero, set **peak_length = Cp+Cn**. If we reached the end of the array and no reset is made, then the peak length is **Cp+Cn**.
7. Calculate the **max** of the different peak_length

[image]

**And Here is the Python code**

```
def peaks_and_valleys(A):
    
    Cp, Cn = 0, 0
    longest_path = 0
    peak_dict = {} # Track and save the peaks and their length
    valley = [] # This is just to track and save the valleys
    N = len(A)
    
    for i in range(N-2):
      if A[i+1] > A[i]: # Uphill
        Cp += 1
        if (A[i+1] == A[i+2]): # Uphill and Flat
          Cp, Cn = 0, 0
        if (A[i+1] > A[i]) and (A[i+1] > A[i+2]): # Peak
            peak = A[i+1] # Record and save the peaks
            # Keep incrementing negative counter while going Downhill
            while i< N-2 and A[i+1] > A[i+2]: 
                Cn += 1
                i += 1
            # At the end of the peak, calculate the longest path
            longest_path = max(longest_path, Cp+Cn+1) 
            peak_dict[peak] = longest_path # Track the peaks

      elif A[i+1] < A[i]: # Downhill
        Cn += 1
        if A[i+1] < A[i+2]: # Valley
          valley.append(A[i+1]) # Save the Valleys
          Cp, Cn = 0, 0
      elif (A[i+1] == A[i]) : # Flat
        Cp, Cn = 0, 0

    print("{Peak': 'Peak Lenght}")
    print(peak_dict)
    print("valley",valley)
    
    return longest_path
```